# How can I delete the Terraform State File in Github actions?

Tags: azure, github, terraform, continuous-integration, github-actions

I'm currently working on a pipeline under Github Actions where I'm able to create an Azure Virtual Machine, but if I tried to reuse the same configuration or template, it will delete and apply the new changes due to the State File. However, how can I delete the Terraform State File from Giithub Actions?

Does anyone have any examples that you might want to share?

As an example, this is what I used from my provider:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  client_id       = var.client_id
  use_oidc        = true
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id

}

# Set the terraform backend
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.4.6" # "~> 0.12.20"
  backend "azurerm" {
    use_oidc = true
  }
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.41.0"
    }
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "~> 2.33.0"
    }
  }
}
```

I imagine that I will be able to use blob storage, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time GitHub runs a workflow it uses a new runner, so you actually cannot delete a terraform state from your previous runner because that was an ephemeral environment and anyways your infrastructure on Azure was deployed on success. So, instead, you must store the terraform state in Azure Blob Storage.

First, create an **Storage Account** and a **Blob Container** either with Azure Portal, CLI or any other method you want.

Second (optional), understand how remote state works on Azure before implementing it in your GitHub Action workflow. Follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/alfonsof/terraform-azure-examples/tree/master/code/07-terraform-state) to handle and use the terraform state in your local development (i.e. your terminal with Terraform and Azure CLI installed).

Basically you will need to pass the storage account and blob container information to Terraform

```
terraform {
# Update this block with the location of your terraform state file
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "rg-terraform-github-actions-state"
    storage_account_name = "terraformgithubactions"
    container_name       = "tfstate"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

This block may have more parameters, since, there are several ways to authenticate and authorize Terraform to create resources for you. Some if not all options are described [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/azurerm). In your example you used OpenID Connect (OIDC) therefore keep

```
use_oidc             = true
```

just below the *key* parameter or somewhere at the backend azurerm block.

I am assuming you are already using [hashicorp/setup-terraform@v2 action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/hashicorp-setup-terraform) and most likely you will only need to add some GitHub secrets to pass sensitive values from your authentication.

For OpenID Connect (OIDC), follow [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/github/connect-from-azure?tabs=azure-portal%2Clinux#use-the-azure-login-action-with-openid-connect) and add this code before your workflow jobs

```
#Special permissions required for OIDC authentication
permissions:
  id-token: write
  contents: read

#These environment variables are used by the terraform azure provider to setup OIDD authenticate. 
env:
  ARM_CLIENT_ID: "${{ secrets.AZURE_CLIENT_ID }}"
  ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: "${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}"
  ARM_TENANT_ID: "${{ secrets.AZURE_TENANT_ID }}"
```

A complete example with all of what I mentioned can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/terraform-github-actions).

---

**EDIT**

If all workflows should be really using a different state, then instead of deleting the state and lose track of your infra. I suggest you to use workspaces.

Below I provided an example that will create a different state file within your blob container for each of the runs. So, none of your runs will update your previous infrastructure, unless you select the workspace of it.

```
- name: Terraform Workspace New
  run: |
    workspace_name="jumpbox${{ github.run_number }}"
    terraform workspace new $workspace_name
    terraform workspace select $workspace_name
```

> After this step, simply continue with the rest of your terraform
> commands.

You can totally replace ${{ github.run_number }} by any variable you want. In your example, if you dynamically change the name of the resource group and include a number at the end to identify the jumpbox, you can use that same number at the workspace name. Therefore, a state file for each of your jumpboxes. This will allow you to create infra seamlessly without modifying any of your previous work.

Comment: That's what I thought but what is doing is deleting my current configuration and recreating the new items. I have been using other tfvars files with a different configuration, and is still the same issue.

Comment: If you are using terraform variables that might be the reason why your infrastructure is changing. e.g. a change in a resource group name will actually delete your old resource group and services within it and recreate a new one with all of your resources in it. So, you are already using remote state? What do you mean that is deleting your configuration? your terraform state file?

Comment: I have created several tfvars files with different values required for my project. Since I am working on building jumpboxes, some of the basic configurations in these tfvars files are similar. Within my workflow, I have defined triggers for specifying the directory, tfvars, host pool name, and the number of the host pool. Based on this information, I dynamically change the name of the resource group and include a number at the end to identify the jumpbox that I am creating.

Comment: I believed that by leveraging these dynamic triggers and multiple pipelines, I could create new jump boxes seamlessly without modifying any of my previous work. However, I seem to encounter an issue where it is utilizing remote state, despite me not configuring it at all. This is why is a little bit confusing.

Comment: In that case, you might use workspaces. See edited answer. And anyway I highly suggest to store your state in a remote location like blob storage and not storing it at the github runner, since it will be deleted.

Comment: Yes, I fixed the problem by doing that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a feature request to be able to delete statefiles from within CI actions after you've run `terraform destroy`

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/34172